# Why I have errorRebind result 'javax.validation.ValidatorFactory' must be a class when i run mvn clean install?

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I am developing a GWT app. When I run mvn clean install I got this error:

```
       [INFO]    [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/Users/pgoran/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.4.0/gwt-user-2.4.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/validation/client/spi/GwtValidationProvider.java'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Line 39:  Rebind result 'javax.validation.ValidatorFactory' must be a class
[INFO]    [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/Users/pgoran/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.4.0/gwt-user-2.4.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/validation/client/BaseMessageInterpolator.java'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Line 96:  Rebind result 'com.google.gwt.validation.client.ProviderValidationMessageResolver' must be a class
[INFO]    [ERROR] Cannot proceed due to previous errors
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 40.149 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-25T09:44:03+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 46M/427M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.4.0:compile (default) on project kapua-console: Command [[
[ERROR] C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\bin\java -Xmx2048m -XX:+UseParallelGC -classpath C:\Users\pgoran\Desktop\kapua\console\src\main\java;C:\Users\pgoran\Desktop\kapua\console\target\generated-sources\gwt;C:\Users\pgoran\Desktop\kapua\console\target\generated-sources\annotations;C:\Users\pgoran\Desktop\kapua\console\src\main\resources;C:\Users\pgoran\Desktop\kapua\console\target\classes;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-guice\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-guice-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-commons\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-commons-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\persistence\eclipselink\2.6.3\eclipselink-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\persistence\javax.persistence\2.1.1\javax.persistence-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\persistence\commonj.sdo\2.1.1\commonj.sdo-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\com\h2database\h2\1.4.192\h2-1.4.192.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\com\google\inject\guice\4.1.0\guice-4.1.0.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\19.0\guava-19.0.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\commons-configuration\commons-configuration\1.9\commons-configuration-1.9.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-account-internal\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-account-internal-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-account-api\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-account-api-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-service-api\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-service-api-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-core\3.1.2\metrics-core-3.1.2.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-security-authorization-api\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-security-authorization-api-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-device-registry-internal\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-device-registry-internal-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-device-call-api\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-device-call-api-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-device-registry-api\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-device-registry-api-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-message-internal\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-message-internal-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.5\jaxb-impl-2.2.5.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-user-internal\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-user-internal-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-user-api\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-user-api-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-security-shiro\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-security-shiro-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-security-authentication-api\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-security-authentication-api-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\apache\shiro\shiro-core\1.2.3\shiro-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.8.3\commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\4.1.3.RELEASE\spring-security-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.3.2.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.3.2.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\4.3.2.RELEASE\spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\4.3.2.RELEASE\spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.3.2.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-device-call-kura\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-device-call-kura-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-transport-api\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-transport-api-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-pool2\2.3\commons-pool2-2.3.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-translator-api\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-translator-api-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\paho\org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3\1.1.0\org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.1.0.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\com\google\protobuf\protobuf-java\2.6.1\protobuf-java-2.6.1.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-device-api\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-device-api-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-message-api\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-message-api-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-device-commons\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-device-commons-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-device-bundle-internal\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-device-bundle-internal-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-device-bundle-api\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-device-bundle-api-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-device-command-internal\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-device-command-internal-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-device-command-api\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-device-command-api-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-device-configuration-internal\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-device-configuration-internal-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-device-configuration-api\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-device-configuration-api-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\joda-time\joda-time\2.9.4\joda-time-2.9.4.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-device-packages-internal\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-device-packages-internal-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-device-packages-api\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-device-packages-api-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-datastore-api\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-datastore-api-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-datastore-internal\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-datastore-internal-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\2.3.4\elasticsearch-2.3.4.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-core\5.5.0\lucene-core-5.5.0.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-backward-codecs\5.5.0\lucene-backward-codecs-5.5.0.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-analyzers-common\5.5.0\lucene-analyzers-common-5.5.0.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-queries\5.5.0\lucene-queries-5.5.0.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-memory\5.5.0\lucene-memory-5.5.0.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-highlighter\5.5.0\lucene-highlighter-5.5.0.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-queryparser\5.5.0\lucene-queryparser-5.5.0.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-sandbox\5.5.0\lucene-sandbox-5.5.0.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-suggest\5.5.0\lucene-suggest-5.5.0.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-misc\5.5.0\lucene-misc-5.5.0.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-join\5.5.0\lucene-join-5.5.0.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-grouping\5.5.0\lucene-grouping-5.5.0.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-spatial\5.5.0\lucene-spatial-5.5.0.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-spatial3d\5.5.0\lucene-spatial3d-5.5.0.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\com\spatial4j\spatial4j\0.5\spatial4j-0.5.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\elasticsearch\securesm\1.0\securesm-1.0.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\com\carrotsearch\hppc\0.7.1\hppc-0.7.1.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\joda\joda-convert\1.2\joda-convert-1.2.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.6.6\jackson-core-2.6.6.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\dataformat\jackson-dataformat-smile\2.6.6\jackson-dataformat-smile-2.6.6.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\dataformat\jackson-dataformat-yaml\2.6.6\jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.6.6.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.15\snakeyaml-1.15.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\dataformat\jackson-dataformat-cbor\2.6.6\jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.6.6.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty\3.10.5.Final\netty-3.10.5.Final.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\com\ning\compress-lzf\1.0.2\compress-lzf-1.0.2.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\com\tdunning\t-digest\3.0\t-digest-3.0.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\hdrhistogram\HdrHistogram\2.1.6\HdrHistogram-2.1.6.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\commons-cli\commons-cli\1.3.1\commons-cli-1.3.1.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\com\twitter\jsr166e\1.1.0\jsr166e-1.1.0.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-translator-kura-mqtt\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-translator-kura-mqtt-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-translator-kapua-kura\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-translator-kapua-kura-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\persistence\org.eclipse.persistence.moxy\2.6.3\org.eclipse.persistence.moxy-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\persistence\org.eclipse.persistence.core\2.6.3\org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\persistence\org.eclipse.persistence.asm\2.6.3\org.eclipse.persistence.asm-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\javax.json\1.0.4\javax.json-1.0.4.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\kapua\kapua-transport-mqtt\0.2.0-SNAPSHOT\kapua-transport-mqtt-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-user\2.4.0\gwt-user-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\com\extjs\gxt\2.2.5\gxt-2.2.5.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\com\allen-sauer\gwt\log\gwt-log\3.1.8\gwt-log-3.1.8.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.1.0.Final\validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\commons-fileupload\commons-fileupload\1.2.2\commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.9\commons-codec-1.9.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\apache\sanselan\sanselan\0.97-incubator\sanselan-0.97-incubator.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\apache\velocity\velocity\1.7\velocity-1.7.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.1\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.4\commons-lang-2.4.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\apache\shiro\shiro-web\1.2.3\shiro-web-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi\3.7\poi-3.7.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi-ooxml\3.7\poi-ooxml-3.7.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi-ooxml-schemas\3.7\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.7.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlbeans\xmlbeans\2.3.0\xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\stax\stax-api\1.0.1\stax-api-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec\1.0\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.0.b2\xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\com\opencsv\opencsv\3.7\opencsv-3.7.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.3.2\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\gwtopenmaps\openlayers\gwt-openlayers-client\0.9\gwt-openlayers-client-0.9.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\mortbay\jetty\jetty-util\6.1.26\jetty-util-6.1.26.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.7.2\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.2\slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-user\2.4.0\gwt-user-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar;C:\Users\pgoran\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-dev\2.4.0\gwt-dev-2.4.0.jar com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler -gen C:\Users\pgoran\Desktop\kapua\console\target\.generated -logLevel INFO -style OBF -war C:\Users\pgoran\Desktop\kapua\console\target -localWorkers 4 -draftCompile -optimize 9 org.eclipse.kapua.app.console.console
[ERROR] ]] failed with status 1
```

I have read somewhere that the problem is maybe we instantiate async interface, and I will give you part of my code where I am doing it:

```
private ConfigurationEntityServiceAsync configurationEntityServiceAsync = GWT.create(ConfigurationEntityService.class);
```

And this is the interface that extends RemoteService(again,I say that I am not sure if this with interfaces is important for this error):

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("goran")
public interface ConfigurationEntityService extends RemoteService {

    public GWTConfiguration create(GWTConfigurationCreator gwtConfigurationCreator)
            throws GwtKapuaException;
    public GWTConfiguration find(String id) throws GwtKapuaException;
    public ListLoadResult<GWTConfiguration> findAll() throws GwtKapuaException;
    public GWTConfiguration update(GWTConfiguration configuration) throws GwtKapuaException;
    public void delete(String id) throws GwtKapuaException;
}
```

Could someone helps me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `javax.validation.ValidatorFactory` on the classpath when the GWT compiler is running?

Comment: No it is not on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the classes which GWT needs are on the classpath when you run the compiler. GWT needs to examine the classes byte code to generate the necessary JavaScript.

Comment: Until yesterday all has worked, and I did not change anything, I really dont know why this problem appeared.

Comment: @Atenica check your version control for all those changes which you don't remember :-) One of them broke your project.

Comment: Well, I don't have version control :)

Comment: In that case, you now know why you should consider it :-)

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**
The problem vas very stupid. I have added methods for update and delete after I generated ConfigurationEntityServiceAsync interface, and when I added this methods I selected option "Generate delete and update methods in ConfigurationEntityServiceAsync " and Eclipse did not refresh method ConfigurationEntityServiceAsync config= GWT.create(ConfigurationEntityService.class) in my client-side class, so i deleted that part in my class ad agaoin wrote it and that is it!